# UWP: Go back a page with databound items

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have a dataset with parameters "name", "location" (or "room" if you want) and "location2" (or "floor"), like this:

```
Location2      Location       Name
1st floor      Living room    Lights
1st floor      Living room    Temperature
1st floor      Living room    Thermostat
1st floor      Kitchen        Lights     
2nd floor      Bedroom        Lights
```

and so on.

I have two ComboBoxes bound to Location2 and Location respectively. The items for "Location" is depending on witch "Location2" is selected. When you first select a floor ("Location") and then a room ("Location"), you get all the devices in the selected room.

This works great, like this:

[image: Devices]
Here's the code for the binding:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Location2Combobox" Margin="5,10,5,5" Width="120" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Location2, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.Location2Filter, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<ComboBox x:Name="Location1Combobox" Margin="5,10,5,5" Width="120" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Location1, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.Location1Filter, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The comboboxes is databound on OnNavigatedToAsync()

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{
....
    if (Location2 == null) Location2 = (from d in App.HS.DeviceList
                                        orderby d.location2 ascending
                                        select d.location2).Distinct().ToList();

    if (Location1 == null) Location1 = (from d in App.HS.DeviceList
                                        where d.location2 == Location2Filter
                                        orderby d.location ascending
                                            select d.location).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

... but the datasource for Location1Combobox is also updated when Location2Filter is updated. (When the user picks a floor, the combobox for the rooms is updated).

```
    string _Location2Filter = "";
    public string Location2Filter
    {
        get { return _Location2Filter; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _Location2Filter, value);
            UpdateLocation1();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateLocation1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MainPageViewModel UpdateLocation1(), navigateBack: " + navigateBack.ToString());

        if (Location2Filter != "")
        {
            Location1 = (from d in App.HS.DeviceList
                         where d.location2 == Location2Filter
                         orderby d.location ascending
                         select d.location).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
```

**All this works well! :)**

However, when I click on a ListItem, I navigate to a new page.
***But when I go back, the Room combobox is reset!***
Because of the NavigationCacheMode, the floor combobox selects the last selected value. But not the room combobox.

I cannot wrap my head around what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo and reproduced your problem. And during debugging I found the problem lies in the following codes:

```
public string Location2Filter
{
    get { return _Location2Filter; }
    set
    {
        Set(ref _Location2Filter, value);
        UpdateLocation1();
    }
}
```

Everytime it navigates to a new page the `updateLocation()` will be called, which results in empty the location1 combobox.

To fix this problem, you can edit the codes like below:

```
public string Location2Filter
{
    get { return _Location2Filter; }
    set
    {
        if (_Location2Filter != value) {
            Set(ref _Location2Filter, value);
            UpdateLocation1();
        }
    }
}
```